# Git how to view the change history/deletion of a function?

Tags: php, git, gitlab

I am trying to find a function that was deleted at some point in time. I tried to use `git log -L :<funcname>:<file>` to locate the function that was deleted. The result ends up being `fatal: -L parameter '<funcname>' starting at line 1: no match`.

For example if I am searching for function `findMe`.

I enter `git log -L :findMe:index.php`

`index.php`

```
 <?php
 class stuff {.....}
 class otherStuff{....}
 class moreStuff{
   public function test(){...}
   public function findMe() {....}
   public function test1() {....}
 }
?>
```

Result `fatal: -L parameter '<funcname>' starting at line 1: no match`.

Reference [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log/):

> **-L :<funcname>:<file>**
>
> If `“:<funcname>”` is given in place of `<start>` and `<end>`, it is a regular expression that denotes the range from the first funcname line that matches `<funcname>`, up to the next funcname line. `“:<funcname>”` searches from the end of the previous `-L` range, if any, otherwise from the start of file. `“^:<funcname>”` searches from the start of file.

Answer (score 1):

`-L` can only find things that exist in the version of the file being shown.

(The error message you quoted suggests that you were passing the literal string `<funcname>` to your command, rather than the string `findMe`.  However, if `findMe` no longer exists in the current or specified version of `index.php`, `-L` won't be able to find it anyway.)

To find commits that *change the number of occurrences* of a string or regular expression, or *affect a line that matches* a string or regular expression, use `git log -S` or `git log -G`.  Note that `-S` takes a string by default while `-G` takes a regular expression (always).  To make `-S` search for a regular expression, rather than a simple string, add `--pickaxe-regex`.  You may limit such searches to particular paths (as many path names as you like, vs `-L`, which *must* search exactly *one* file).

Hence, if `findMe` used to exist in `index.php` but no longer does exist in `index.php`, the command:

```
git log -S findMe --full-history -- index.php
```

will find all commit that changes this, because it will go from one or more occurrences in `index.php` to zero occurrences in `index.php`.  Note, however, that adding the path name `index.php` turns on history simplification.  Using `--full-history` disables this simplification, so that you can find *all* commits that deleted it, rather than just *some* commit (which sometimes fails if the deletion came about through a merge).

Answer (score 1):

That should be easier with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).
Before, "[`git blame -L :funcname -- path`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/3f6dc9c36693c2ba6dd5fb61fbad6b72cc08e3d1/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L12)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--Lltstartgtltendgt))</sup> did not work well for a path for which a userdiff driver is defined.

See [commit 3af31e8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3af31e87868d46363359148db5243f46d49029e8), [commit 88894aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88894aaeeae92e8cb41143cc2e045f50289dc790), [commit 9466e38](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230), [commit 180d641](https://github.com/git/git/commit/180d641d7d71ba45a140e9c83777d30be59c4274), [commit 0cce88f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0cce88f1e4b0ccbdc804db8b522aeb11b0f2b199), [commit a4514a4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a4514a46d9c85278ae4a350442dd4a160ff1f3cf), [commit fd5c74e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fd5c74e7818a478fac66d821c38c4c2275c77da6), [commit f9c8d8c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f9c8d8cbbea9cc55d26058a1de767731600ded44) (01 Nov 2020) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 3f6dc9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3f6dc9c36693c2ba6dd5fb61fbad6b72cc08e3d1), 18 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`blame`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230): enable `funcname` blaming with `userdiff` driver
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> In [`blame.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230/blame.c)::cmd_blame, we send the 'path' field of the '`sb`' 'struct `blame_scoreboard`' as the '`path`' argument to '[`line-range.c::parse_range_arg`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230/line-range.c)', but '`sb.path`' is not set yet; it's set to the local variable '`path`' a few lines later at line 1137.
>
> This '`path`' argument is only used in '`parse_range_arg`' if we are blaming a funcname, i.e. [`git blame -L :<funcname> <path>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230/Documentation/blame-options.txt#L12)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt--Lltstartgt,ltendgt))</sup>, and in that case it is sent to '`parse_range_funcname`', where it is used to determine if a `userdiff` driver should be used for said `<path>` to match the given funcname.
>
> Since '`path`' is yet unset, the userdiff driver is never used, so we fall back to the default funcname regex, which is usually not appropriate for paths that are set to use a specific userdiff driver, and thus either we match some unrelated lines, or we die with
>
> ```
> fatal: -L parameter '<funcname>' starting at line 1: no match
> ```
>
> This has been the case ever since [`git blame`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9466e3809d2b5f9605918c56d63f21b17e98e230/Documentation/git-blame.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame))</sup> learned to blame a `funcname` in [13b8f68c1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/13b8f68c1f0b6d4ff5a7bed5a834e7e5e34a9fd0) ("`log -L`: `:pattern:file` syntax to find by `funcname`", 2013-03-28, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed73fe56428eecd2b635473f6a517a183c4713a3)).
>
> Enable funcname blaming for paths using specific userdiff drivers by initializing '`sb.path`' earlier in '`cmd_blame`', when some of its other fields are initialized, so that it is set when passed to '`parse_range_arg`'.

Comment: This is the answer IMO. But, to my chagrin, as of `git version 2.35.1`, if you are looking for a function that is a member function of a C++ class, and you do what is reasonable to want to do, which is to fully qualify the function name along with the class name like this: `git blame -L :SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction -- ./some_source_file.cpp`, it returns with a usage error. [cont'd]

Comment: [cont'd] Instead, you have to remove the `SomeClass::` qualifier like this:  `git blame -L :SomeMemberFunction -- ./some_source_file.cpp`. IMO, that can potentially be a time-waster: What if you unfortunately are studying code that defines two or more classes in the same source file, each containing definitions of `SomeMemberFunction`, then which class'es member function will git choose to analyze?

Comment: @bgoodr That seems unfortunate indeed. Did you try with quotes? `-L ":SomeClass::SomeMemberFunction"`?

Comment: Given that the interactive shell I was using was bash running on a Linux platform, and the colon characters are not metacharacters in that shell, at least in that usage, the double quotes would be redundant.

Answer (score 0):

`git log -L` only searches for a funcname on the highest level of the file. You can use the command to see the history of any of your classes or any function outside of a class, but unfortunately it can't find functions inside of a class.

The best you can do is to `git log -L :moreStuff:index.php`, and search the output for the function logs.

Comment: Please clarify what "on the highest level of the file" means here.